# How do I call AES/ECB 64k times efficiently?

Tags: android, performance, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am working on a library for MEGA (the cloud site of this strange person). If I got it right, they derive a AES masterkey from the users password by:

- Use UTF-8 encoding of password as start sequence s
- Expand s by appending 0 such that its length is a multiple of 16
- Set 128 bit masterkey pkey to fix init vector
- In each of 64k rounds:

  - For each 128 bit block s[i] of s AES/ECB encrypt k using s[i] as key.

All in all, for a 28 character password, I have to make 128k calls to AES. My implementation turns out to be rather slow. As in: "Hell, that takes way too long."

DDMS shows me that the GC is running hot. How can I get the AES implementation to do all those rounds internally or at least more efficiently? Each call creates a new byte array that is thrown away afterwards. Is there a way to do this inplace?

```
public static byte[] calculatePasswordKey(String password) {
    Log.v(TAG, ">calculatePasswordKey");

    byte[] pw = password.getBytes();
    byte[] pkey = {(byte)0x93, (byte)0xC4, 0x67, (byte)0xE3, 0x7D, (byte)0xB0, (byte)0xC7, (byte)0xA4, (byte)0xD1, (byte)0xBE, 0x3F, (byte)0x81, 0x01, 0x52, (byte)0xCB, 0x56};

    //expand by appending 0s
    Log.v(TAG, Arrays.toString(pw));
    if ((pw.length & 0xf0) != 0) {
        int l = (pw.length & 0xf0) + 0x10;
        byte[] paddedpw = new byte[l];
        System.arraycopy(pw, 0, paddedpw, 0, pw.length);
        pw = paddedpw;
        Log.v(TAG, Arrays.toString(pw));
    }

    try {
        //create ciphers only once
        Cipher[] ciphers = new Cipher[pw.length / 16];
        Log.v(TAG, "Creating " + ciphers.length + " AES ciphers");
        for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < ciphers.length; cIndex++) {
            ciphers[cIndex] = getAesEcbCipher();
            ciphers[cIndex].init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(pw, cIndex * 16, 16, "AES"));
        }

        Log.v(TAG, "Beginning 65536 rounds of AES encryption");
        for (int round = 0; round < 65536; round--) {
            for (Cipher c: ciphers) {
                pkey = c.update(pkey);
                if (pkey.length != 16) {
                    throw new Error("update does not work, revert to doFinal()");
                }
            }
        }
        return pkey;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot calculate password key: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks a lot,
Volker

Comment: Uhm. I wonder if "PKDBF-2" would be of relevance? ^^

Comment: A bit of advice: Avoid MEGA for a short while, at least. Currently it uses encryption mechanisms which are not considered secure by *any* measure. https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbo=d&q=dotcom+mega+security+hole

Comment: I wish. Unfortunately, it looks like they had to create their own key derivation instead of using something established. To me, this looks nothing like PKDBF.

Comment: @Eric thx. Although, I really dislike Kim, I longed for a client-based-encryption cloud for years. As I see it, all problems stem from MEGA using javascript loaded from their servers. An Android app using strong crypto libraries should solve these problems, at least if you never use the javascript site (including registration).

Comment: True indeed. It was more of a notification than anything; just thought anyone developing for MEGA ought to know.

Comment: Also: Once I reach beta stadium, I will put it on github under some CC and have security guys yell at me :)
If I get it right, nothing that MEGA f*cks up should compromise security (as long as you don't use their website).

Comment: Are you sure this is really the right derivation algorithm? Does it produce the right key? Using 16 different instances of Ciphers seems rather weird. BTW, password derivation is intended to be slow, in order to make brute forcing harder.

Comment: Use c.update(input, offset, length, output, offset) to avoid allocations. Or, at least, get as close as possible.

Comment: Are you sure about the `round--` in `for (int round = 0; round < 65536; round--)`?

Comment: OMG! I feel so incredibly stupid now. I guess that happens if you code all night long m)
Thanks a million. Of course, that was the problem.
Important lesson: never rewrite ugly stuff (it used to be a countdown) until the system runs.

Comment: It is still a "PBKDF" without salt though, removing one of the principle inputs.

Comment: @Nikolay: I am pretty sure. Also it generates a cipher for each 128 bit block of the UTF-8 representation. I.e., a 28 character password results in two ciphers that are both applied in all rounds.

Comment: @kroot thx! The problem was me being to stupid to code a simple for-loop, but your suggestion improved performance once I solved that problem. I am now down to 1s for key derivation which is perfectly OK since it is done in an AsyncTask anyway.

Comment: @owlstead does that mean I could simply call some crypto API to replace my method? I would really like to do that: the less crypto stuff I have to code, the less errors I can make.

Comment: @Volker Throw the first stone who never did something similar :) glad to help!

Comment: @Volker sure, if you are ok with replacing the algorithm you should use PBKDF2, look for it on this site, it is part of the Sun provider, in the standard runtime and Android as well. Check e.g. [here](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-password-based-encryption-on.html) and use `"PBKDF2WithHMACSHA1"`.

Comment: @JoãoFernandes I think you should post this as an answer, although Volker may want to delete the question eventually, I don't think too many people will benefit from the answer - except Volker himself of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For archiving purpose I'm writing my comment as an answer, as some of the comments may be useful to someone in the future.

The problem is the `count--` in the second for loop. It should be a `count++`. As it is, the code is performing 2^31 rounds, i.e., 2147483648 instead of the desired 65536.